# How to read a list in python? ,=row and space=column

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I need to read a file .txt. 
At the beginning file is:

```
['                                                                                                   5                                                                                                   \n', '                                                                                                  1 9                                                                                                  \n', '                                                                                                 3 8 3                                                                                                 \n', '                                                                                                7 5 6 1                                                                                                \n', '                                                                                               3 9 5 6 1                                                                                               \n', '                                                                                              3 7 2 1 8 3
```

(...)

I deleted blank places and I have that:

```
['5', '1 9', '3 8 3', '7 5 6 1', '3 9 5 6 1', '3 7 2 1 8 3', '9 6 4 3 9 1 5', '3 8 4 5 3 7 5 8', '7 1 9 4 1 3 1 9 3', '4 8 9 2 5 6 7 3 7 3', '4 2 5 1 5 9 8 3 7 8 4', '9 7 6 1 9 4 9 2 9 1 6 9', '6 2 5 7 3 5 4 5 3 2 7 8 1', '7 4 3 5 3 9 5 9 3 5 3 1 3 9', '8 2 7 3 1 4 2 6 4 8 7 3 5 8 1', '7 2 9 4 6 4 1 6 9 6 4 3 9 8 5 4', '7 9 8 7 8 9 1 2 6 4 8 9 1 8 4 6 9', '1 4 7 9 6 5 3 8 6 4 2 1 7 4 1 9 3 1', '6 8 6 2 9 4 9 6 3 7 3 8 7 8 6 9 3 2 7', '4 7 4 1 9 6 7 2 1 3 2 6 9 4 1 7 6 5 4 5', '2 5 4 7 6 9 6 1 4 7 1 4 5 1 2 6 2 1 3 1 4', '6 7 1 6 1 4 3 7 9 2 5 8 9 4 8 1 2 1 5 6 7 8', '9 3 2 1 4 8 3 5 2 1 9 1 4 8 3 9 4 1 5 3 1 4 1', '9 3 1 9 8 9 7 4 2 9 4 3 7 3 1 7 5 8 2 8 3 8 1 5', '6 5 3 6 4 1 9 8 2 6 2 3 9 8 7 9 6 3 7 1 2 8 2 7 3', '4 1 4 2 4 1 2 3 8 1 5 8 6 8 7 3 4 7 8 2 8 1 2 3 5 6', '2 9 1 2 8 2 5 9 7 8 1 6 9 2 6 8 4 7 1 9 8 4 3 6 3 9 7', '8 2 7 6 9 7 3 4 1 4 6 1 7 6 2 9 4 8 6 2 1 8 2 7 8 5 1 6', '5 4 7 3 5 2 1 8 3 7 8 6 5 6 7 8 1 3 4 9 1 6 8 4 8 6 3 4 8', '7 8 9 2 9 1 3 1 8 3 9 6 4 2 7 3 7 2 3 1
```

(...)

I need to write it the , as row and space as column. I don't know how to do that. Nohing work fine.
Here's my code:

```
import csv
import numpy
import logging
data=[]
clean_data=[]
with open('cos.txt', 'r') as fname:
  data=fname.readlines()
  print(data)
  for x in data:
    #print(x.strip())
    val=x.strip()
    clean_data.append(val)
    clean_data_1=list(filter(''.__ne__,clean_data))
#print(data)
#print(len(data))
print(clean_data)
print(len(clean_data))
print(clean_data_1)
print(len(clean_data_1))
type(clean_data_1)
```

I need that data as:

```
[[5], [1, 9], [3, 8, 3]...]
```

Comment: Seriously - from what you posted I have no clue what you want to achieve. Maybe dumb down the data and make a small input/output example so e can see from where you come and where you want to go to?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work ...

```
result = [[int(c) for c in string.split()] for string in clean_data]
```

```
>>>result
[[5], [1, 9], [3, 8, 3], [7, 5, 6, 1], [3, 9, 5, 6, 1], [3, 7, 2, 1, 8, 3], [9, 6, 4, 3, 9, 1, 5], [3, 8, 4, 5, 3, 7, 5, 8], [7, 1, 9, 4, 1, 3, 1, 9, 3], [4, 8, 9, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 7, 3], [4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 8, 4], [9, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 9, 2, 9, 1, 6, 9],...]
```